# GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIqx6YRS/libpython3.10.so.1.0)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, glibc

my command `./orthofinder -f /folder`

Full error: `[28887] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIqx6YRS/libpython3.10.so.1.0': dlopen: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /tmp/_MEIqx6YRS/libpython3.10.so.1.0)`

I am trying to run a command line (`orthofinder`) but I get this error constantly. I have searched online for potential answers but nothing seems to work for me.
My GLIBC version is 2.27 and I know that the requirement apparently should be 3.35.

```
ldd --version 
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.6) 2.27
```

However in another PC that I have tried it with GLIBC 2.31 it works perfectly.
Moreover,
`sudo apt update` or `sudo apt upgrade` do not seem to help either since the version of GLIBC doesn't change. Also I have installed the latest version of python too, but I dont know how relevant is this. The Ubuntu version that I have is the following:

```
Linux Mint 19 "Tara," which is based on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS "Bionic Beaver."
```

So does anyone can help with this problem? I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

> My GLIBC version is 2.27 and I know that the requirement apparently should be 3.35.

Correct.

> However in another PC that I have tried it with GLIBC 2.31 it works perfectly.

Note that the version requirement doesn't come from the `orthofinder` binary; it comes from `libpython3.10.so.1.0` that it uses.

I don't know the origin of `/tmp/_MEIqx6YRS/libpython3.10.so.1.0`, but on the GLIBC-2.31 system your binary must use a *different* `libpython3.10.so.1.0` or it would have had the same problem.

The `/tmp/...` path suggests that that `libpython3.10.so.1.0` may be embedded into the `orthofinder` binary itself. Are you *sure* you are using the same `orthofinder` binary on both systems?

> sudo apt upgrade do not seem to help either since the version of GLIBC

It is usual for the `apt upgrade` etc. to *never* update GLIBC major.minor version, because doing so can cause all kinds of failures.

> Also I have installed the latest version of python too

The `/tmp/_MEIqx6YRS/libpython3.10.so.1.0` isn't coming from system Python; it's coming from somewhere *else*.

The `orthofinder` might be an open-source program ([this one](https://github.com/davidemms/OrthoFinder)?).

If so, your best solution is to *build* it yourself on your system.

Comment: The app is built with PyInstaller. (MEI in the temp path is the clue.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for your replies and sorry for this late answer.

I figured out the problem by changing to an earliest version of Orthofinder. It is recommended in their github account (https://github.com/davidemms/OrthoFinder). So I would suggest that since by upgrading or downgrading GLIBC it can be apparently quite problematic. Thanks a lot. I found a relative question and answer in this post (https://github.com/davidemms/OrthoFinder/issues/305).